# SQL server uft8 connection

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm using SQL server with an intranet application written in PHP. For convenience i want to use UTF8 charset for web pages (jquery supports only utf8) however all data stored in my sqlserver db is in iso-8859-1.
Can I change just the data CONNECTION CHARSET (not data store charset) between sqlserver and PHP? Maybe just with a query header?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server only stores Unicode data in tables prefixed with `N` (so `NVARCHAR` etc). These are stored in the UCS-2 format. The Windows SQLSRV driver will convert those columns from `UCS-2` to `UTF-8` when retrieving, and the opposite when saving.

However, if the data is `ISO-8859-1` (non-`N` columns) then you will need to convert the text yourself. I would suggest creating a wrapper function on your data retrieval methods to convert `ISO-8859-1` data to UTF-8.